# How to powershell curl emailrep.io

Tags: json, powershell, curl

When I try to use Powershell to perform a curl command on emailrep.io I do not get the proper output.

I have tried the following three commands, however they do not return the expected output, namely a proper formatted JSON:

```bsh
curl emailrep.io/bsheffield432@gmail.com
Invoke-RestMethod emailrep.io/bsheffield432@gmail.com
Invoke-WebRequest emailrep.io/bsheffield432@gmail.com
```

The output of the last command looks as follows

```bsh
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                      <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
                        <meta name="description" content="">...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Accept-Ranges: bytes
                    Content-Length: 16661
                    Content-Type: text/html
                    Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2019 13:44:10 GMT
                    ETag: "5d3f381c-4115"
                    Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Jul 20...
Forms             : {search-form}
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [Accept-Ranges, bytes], [Content-Length, 16661], [Content-Type,
                    text/html]...}
Images            : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG style="WIDTH: 35px" src="./assets/img/logo-light.png">;
                    outerText=; tagName=IMG; style=WIDTH: 35px; src=./assets/img/logo-light.png}, @{innerHTML=;
                    innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG src="./assets/img/social_twitter.png" width=19>; outerText=;
                    tagName=IMG; src=./assets/img/social_twitter.png; width=19}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=;
                    outerHTML=<IMG src="./assets/img/github_logo.png" width=20>; outerText=; tagName=IMG;
                    src=./assets/img/github_logo.png; width=20}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG
                    class=company-logo-img src="">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; class=company-logo-img; src=}...}
InputFields       : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT id=search-input class="search-input form-control
                    form-control-lg" name=search-input placeholder="Enter an email">; outerText=; tagName=INPUT;
                    id=search-input; class=search-input form-control form-control-lg; name=search-input;
                    placeholder=Enter an email}}
Links             : {@{innerHTML=<IMG style="WIDTH: 35px" src="./assets/img/logo-light.png"> ; innerText= ;
                    outerHTML=<A id=home-link href="https://emailrep.io"><IMG style="WIDTH: 35px"
                    src="./assets/img/logo-light.png"> </A>; outerText= ; tagName=A; id=home-link;
                    href=https://emailrep.io}, @{innerHTML=API; innerText=API; outerHTML=<A class=nav-link
                    href="#api">API</A>; outerText=API; tagName=A; class=nav-link; href=#api}, @{innerHTML=Contact;
                    innerText=Contact; outerHTML=<A class=nav-link href="/contact">Contact</A>; outerText=Contact;
                    tagName=A; class=nav-link; href=/contact}, @{innerHTML=Docs; innerText=Docs; outerHTML=<A
                    class=nav-link href="/docs">Docs</A>; outerText=Docs; tagName=A; class=nav-link; href=/docs}...}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 16661
```

I installed curl for windows and I can get it to work with the following command. However there should be a powershell alternative to perform this.

```bsh
curl.exe emailrep.io/bsheffield432@gmail.com
{
  "email": "bsheffield432@gmail.com",
  "reputation": "none",
  "suspicious": true,
  "references": 0,
  "details": {
    "blacklisted": false,
    "malicious_activity": false,
    "malicious_activity_recent": false,
    "credentials_leaked": false,
    "credentials_leaked_recent": false,
    "data_breach": false,
    "last_seen": "never",
    "domain_exists": true,
    "domain_reputation": "n/a",
    "new_domain": false,
    "days_since_domain_creation": 8760,
    "suspicious_tld": false,
    "spam": false,
    "free_provider": true,
    "disposable": false,
    "deliverable": true,
    "accept_all": false,
    "valid_mx": true,
    "spoofable": true,
    "spf_strict": true,
    "dmarc_enforced": false,
    "profiles": []
  }
}
```

This is HTML and not JSON.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which kind of request (GET, POST) do you want to send? Could you also please clarify what is command and what is error message?

Comment: I am using a GET request. The expected output would be in JSON format however when I try using one of the power shell native commands such as Invoke-WebRequest I get the html from the website.

Comment: It may be easier if I add the DOC API: https://emailrep.io/docs/?shell#query-an-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emailrep.io` seems to be doing a naive check for `curl` in the user-agent string. Override the user-agent string with `Invoke-WebRequest` and you should get the expected response:

```
$rep = Invoke-WebRequest https://emailrep.io/bill@microsoft.com -UserAgent not_actually_curl |ConvertFrom-Json

# Since we piped it to `ConvertFrom-Json`, $rep is now a structured object:
if($rep.reputation -ne 'high' -or $rep.suspicious){
    Write-Warning "<$($rep.email)> is not to be trusted!"
}
```

---

*I [reached out](https://github.com/sublime-security/emailrep.io/issues/3) to the maintainer of `emailrep.io` and they actually updated the API to always return json for non-browsers (including Windows PowerShell web cmdlets), so the above should no longer be necessary*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it is necessary to use `curl` if you have Powershell-native commands.

Assume you want to perform the following GET-request

```
curl -X GET "http://me:mypassword@myserver.com:1234/"
```

The same thing in PowerShell is slightly longer:

```bsh
$user = 'me'
$pass = 'mypass'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://myserver.com:1234' -Headers $Headers
```

If you do not need authentication, it would be

```
curl -X GET "http://myserver.com:1234/"
```

which is then also easy in PowerShell:

```bsh
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://myserver.com:1234'
```

Further reading on parsing JSON with PowerShell:

- [How to parse JSON from the Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762615/how-to-parse-json-from-the-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell)

The solution offered there to receive nice JSON back is

```bsh
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://myserver.com:1234/"
$jsonObj = ConvertFrom-Json $([String]::new($response.Content))
```

Comment: There is no authentication required. So I would assume the following would work `Invoke-WebRequest emailrep.io/bsheffield432@gmail.com`