# How would you get the values returned and put into a variable?

Tags: powershell, rest

I'm looking to connect to an API using PowerShell and get some info to generate a spreadsheet.

I'm very new to API and scripting, but learning...

I'm looking for assistance, or some document that might help me...

When sending API Get requests, how wouldyou capture the important information returned?

For example, if I want to connect and get an OAUTH Code...  How would you capture it into a variable to use in the next command to obtain the access token?

I appreciate your assistance, as this community has already taught me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start:

[How to parse JSON from the Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762615/how-to-parse-json-from-the-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell)

Generally the topics you will want to look for are:

- Formatting HTTP requests
- Sending HTTP requests
- Parsing HTTP responses